# Redirect user to a sub folder after logging in FTP

Tags: configuration, ftp, vsftpd

I want to redirect user after SFTP log in to public_html folder.

I have tried this script in `vsftpd.conf`

```
user_sub_token=$USER
local_root=/home/$USER/public_html
listen=YES
```

This does not work does anyone know the reason why?

Answer (score 0):

SFTP is a file transfer protocol over SSH and has nothing to do with FTP (except parts of the name). To add to the confusion: there is FTPS which is FTP, but with SSL. So if you want to restrict SFTP it is wrong to edit the config of the FTP-Daemon. For SFTP restriction http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/590 might help.

Comment: Okay Thanks, I think my focus is on FTP and when the user logs in through that I want them to land on /home/user/public_html